# Container taking up unnecessary space?

Tags: css, containers

I have a small issue here which I can't quite figure out. I have three containers on one page all below each other. One for buttons, a JS image slideshow and a description box. The image slider seems to take up unnecessary space when the browser is resized activating media queries:

http://gyazo.com/33376dcadc99cba69d5668e240fae788

CSS desktop view (without media queries):

```
body { 
  background: #141414 url('../images/background1.png');
  background-repeat: repeat-y;
  background-attachment:fixed;
  background-position:center;
}
#container{
 height:450px;                                                           
 width:840px;
 margin:120px auto 2% auto;
 position:relative;
}
#container2{
 height:60px;
 width:840px;
 margin:0 auto 50px auto;
 position:relative;
 -moz-box-shadow:0 0 5px 5px black;
 -webkit-box-shadow:0 0 5px 5px black;
 box-shadow:0 0 5px 5px black;
 }
 #container2 p{
 color:white;
 font-size:15px;
 padding-left:5px;
 }
 #container2 h2{
 color:white;
 font-size: 18px;
 text-decoration:none;
 padding-left:5px;
 padding-top:2px;
 }
 #img{
  height:450px;
  width:840px;
  position:absolute; 
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px 5px black;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px 5px black;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px 5px black;
}
#l_holder{
  height:450px;
  width:100px;
  position:absolute;
  left:0px;
  top:0px;  
  cursor:pointer;
}
#r_holder{
  height:450px;
  width:100px;
  position:absolute;
  right:0px;
  top:0px;  
 cursor:pointer;
}
.left{
  height:50px;
  width:50px; 
  position:absolute; 
  top:45%;
  left:0px;
}
.right{
  height:50px;
  width:50px; 
  position:absolute; 
  top:45%;
  right:0px;
}
 .clear{
  clear:bottom;
}
```

CSS with media queries, this is where the container is causing a problem:

```
@media all and (min-width: 3.5in) and (max-width: 10in) {

        body { 
          background: #141414;
        }
        #container{
            height:30%;
            width:100%;
            margin:5% auto;
            padding:0 0 0px 0;
        }

        #container2{
            width:100%;
            margin: 0; padding: 0;
        }
        #container2 p{
            padding-left:3px;
        }
        #container2 h2{
            padding:5px 0 0 3px;
        }
        #container2 .body_black_box{ 
        }
        #img{
            height:80%;                                                          
            width:100%;
        }
        #l_holder{
            height:80%;
        }
        #r_holder{
            height:80%;
        }
        .left{
        }
        .right{
        }
        .clear{
        }
        }
```

If anyone has any ideas, I'd be grateful.

Comment: Same effect, even if I change it to margin:0 auto 0 auto;

Comment: pls share some fiddle code